# retrieving all row's value at a time of a particular table

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a project of attendance management system for a office where leave management system is also included. There is a report showing page where absent/present report of a employee is shown. Now I have to show `in leave` report instead of `absent` report if the particular employee is absent in his leave days and these leave days is determined according to his leave application and stored in database with the applied leave date. I have created a `leave` table where all associated information about `leave` is stored. Here is my `leave` table..

```
lid     empname     username    nod       sdate        edate       reason  action  empID 
===     =======     ========    ===     ==========  ===========    ======  ====== =======
 1      Maxwell       max        1      2013/04/09  2013/04/09      xam   Denied    3
 2      Sukant        suk        1      2013/03/11  2013/03/11      xam   Denied    4
 3      Sukant        suk        1      2013/02/20  2013/02/20      xam   Accepted  4
 4      Taylor        tay        1      2013/05/23  2013/05/23      xam   Accepted  1
 5      Sukant        suk        1      2013/05/23  2013/05/23      xam   Accepted  4
```

The problem is that I can't fetch all the rows of my `leave` table at a time. But I have to fetch all the rows of my `leave` table to check all the `sdate` and `edate` and `action` to show report `in leave` or `absent` in my report page. I have written the following code but it only fetches the very first row or a single row  of `leave` table. It will show `in leave` (if accepted) report in report showing page for only  the row that it is fetching.

```
 <?php
            $leave = mysql_query("SELECT `action` FROM  `leave` 
                            where uname =('SELECT `username` FROM `users` 
                            where `empID` =$user')", $dbCon) 
                            or die(mysql_error());
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `office_date` 
            WHERE year='$year' 
            AND month = '$month' ORDER BY odate DESC ";
            $query = mysql_query($sql, $dbCon);

            $leave_row = mysql_fetch_array($leave);

            $i = 1;
            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($query)){ 

               if(....)
               {

                   //some code here

                } 
                 else if ($leave_row[7] == "accepted" && $leave_row[4]  == $row2->odate)
                 {

                    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '">
                    <td>&nbsp;' . $i . '</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;' . $row2->odate . '</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><font color="red">In leave</font></td>
                </tr>';

                 }
                else {
                    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '">
                    <td>&nbsp;' . $i . '</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;' . $row2->odate . '</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><font color="red">Absent</font></td>
                </tr>';
                }

                $i++;

            }

            ?>
```

The sql query is `SELECT * FROM`leave`where empID = $user` should that fetch only one row of my `leave` table?

My if condition only checks the information of one row. I know why: the query  **$leave = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `leave` where empID = $user ");** only fetches a single row. How can I fetch all the rows and what should be the php code in place of `else if` statement of my code to fetch or check all the rows at a time?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are only fetching a row from first query, you need to loop to retrieve all rows you need

```
$leave_row = mysql_fetch_array($leave);
```

Should be

```
while($leave_row = mysql_fetch_array($leave)) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code has

```
       $leave = mysql_query("SELECT `action` FROM  `leave` 
                        where uname =('SELECT `username` FROM `users` 
                        where `empID` =$user')", $dbCon) 
                        or die(mysql_error());
```

One problem is that you need to remove the `'` marks from the subquery, like so:

```
       $leave = mysql_query("SELECT `action` FROM  `leave` 
                        where uname =(SELECT `username` FROM `users` 
                        where `empID` =$user)", $dbCon) 
                        or die(mysql_error());
```

Assuming that works, can you try this and see what happens?

```
<?php
        $leave_query = mysql_query("SELECT `action` FROM  `leave` 
                        where uname =(SELECT `username` FROM `users` 
                        where `empID` =$user)", $dbCon) 
                        or die(mysql_error());
        $office_date_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `office_date` 
        WHERE year='$year' 
        AND month = '$month' ORDER BY odate DESC", $dbCon)
                        or die(mysql_error());

        // Not sure if we want this to be a 1 or a 0...
        $i = 1;

        while ($office_date_query_results = mysql_fetch_object($office_date_query)){ 
          $office_date_results[] = $office_date_query_results;
        }

        while ($leave_query_results = mysql_fetch_array($leave_query)){ 
          $leave_row[] = $leave_query_results;
        }

        for ($x = 0; $x < count($leave_row); $x++) {

          foreach ($office_date_results as $row2) {

            if (....) {
               //some code here
            } 

            else if ($leave_row[$x][7] == "accepted" && $leave_row[$x][4]  == $row2->odate) {
              echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '">
              <td>&nbsp;' . $i . '</td>
              <td>&nbsp;' . $row2->odate . '</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><font color="red">In leave</font></td>
              </tr>';
            }

            else {
              echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '">
               <td>&nbsp;' . $i . '</td>
               <td>&nbsp;' . $row2->odate . '</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td>&nbsp;</td>
               <td><font color="red">Absent</font></td>
             </tr>';
            }

            $i++;
          }
        }

        ?>
```